# What is wrong with this "if" statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

```
 String letterGrade = "F"; 
if (grade >= 90) { letterGrade = "A"; }
if (grade >= 80) { letterGrade = "B"; } 
if (grade >= 70) { letterGrade = "C"; } 
if (grade >= 60) { letterGrade = "D"; }
```

Just a HW problem I can't figure out.

Comment: Where does `grade` come from?

Comment: Why do you think there's something wrong? Do you get a compile error? If so, then what is the error? Does it compile, but give an unexpected answer? If yes, then what did you expect and what does it really do?

Comment: Try to do it from min to max, so starting at `60`.

Comment: well this can help a lot:
! http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_if_else_statements.html

Answer (score 10):

You should have an `if-else if` ladder:

```
if (grade >= 90) { letterGrade = "A"; }
else if (grade >= 80) { letterGrade = "B"; } 
else if (grade >= 70) { letterGrade = "C"; } 
else if (grade >= 60) { letterGrade = "D"; }
```

.. otherwise all the `if` statements will be executed.

---

You should avoid hardcoding values like that. Consider the case when later on sometime, the grade system changes, and you start providing grade `E` for `grade >= 50`. Then it will be nightmare for you to change the code.

A better to handle this is to use an `enum`. You might notice a behaviour in those ranges. Diving any value in a certain range by 10, will give you the same number. You can use this logic to create an enum of grades:

```
enum Grade {
    A(9), B(8), C(7), D(6);

    private final Grade[] GRADES = values();

    private final int grade;
    private Grade(int grade) { this.grade = grade; }

    public int getGrade() { return this.grade; }        

    public Grade valueOf(int grade) {
        for (Grade grade: GRADES) {
            if (grade.getGrade() == grade / 10)
                return grade;
        } 
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then, for a particular grade value, you can get the letter grade by using `getValue(grade)` method:

```
Grade letterGrade = Grade.valueOf(grade);
```

Now, it's easy to expand the enum when a new grade range is added. Now, this enum wouldn't work if the range is something like - `[85, 100]` for `A`. For that, you can have the value of grade in enum as lower bound, like `85` for `A`. Then change the logic of returning `Grade` to `>` instead of `==`.

There can be other ways to form the logic, but that would depend upon the situation. But this approach will be far more maintainable.

Here's a quote from [Effective Java - Item 50](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683):

> **Strings are poor substitutes for enum types.** As discussed in Item 30,
>   enums make far better enumerated type constants than strings.

Comment: @DarbyVance You're welcome :) You can mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick mark besides it.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions satisfying all the if statements.Use `if else`

```
String letterGrade = "F";
        if (grade >= 90) {
            letterGrade = "A";

        }
        else if (grade >= 80) {
            letterGrade = "B";
        }
        else if (grade >= 70) {
            letterGrade = "C";
        }
        else if (grade >= 60) {
            letterGrade = "D";
        }else {
            letterGrade="none"; //remove else  it. so grade "F"  remain
        }
    }
```